# MySQL 5.5.17 configure.sh Location?

Tags: mysql, macos

So I recently downloaded MySQL 5.5.17, and I'm trying to build it from source on my computer.  The problem is, I can't seem to find the configure.sh script.  I'm fairly certain I downloaded the source code version (mysql-5.5.17.tar) from the MySQL website, which can be found by selecting the "Source Code" drop down on the MySQL dowload page [here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads).

Does anyone know if they changed the location of the script? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I just can't seem to find it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you perchance accidentally download the _precompiled_ `tar.gz` as I just did?

Comment: Pretty sure I grabbed the open source one... All the makefiles are there, just not that one script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to build MySQL 5.5, you need to use CMake.

See http://lenzg.net/archives/329-MySQL-5.5-CMake-replaces-autoconfautomake-on-all-platforms,-support-for-autotools-has-now-been-removed.html